# Synchronous vs asynchronous computation in Tensorflow

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow

In the Tensorflow CIFAR tutorial it talks about using multiple GPUs and gives this warning:

"Naively employing asynchronous updates of model parameters leads to sub-optimal training performance because an individual model replica might be trained on a stale copy of the model parameters. Conversely, employing fully synchronous updates will be as slow as the slowest model replica."

What does this mean? Could someone provide a very simple example that illustrates this warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose you have n workers.

Asynchronous means that each worker just reads parameters, computes updates, and writes updated parameters, without any locking mechanism at all. The workers can overwrite each other's work freely.
Suppose worker 1 is slow for some reason. Worker 1 reads parameters at time t, and then tries to write updated parameters at time t+100. In the meantime, workers 2-n have all done a lot of updates at time step t+1, t+2, etc. When the slow worker 1 finally does its write, it overwrites all of the progress the other workers have made.

Fully synchronous means that all the workers are coordinated. Every worker reads the parameters, computes a gradient, and then waits for the other workers to finish. Then the learning algorithm computes the average of all of the gradients they computed, and does an update based on that one average. If worker 1 is very slow and takes 100 time steps to finish, but workers 2-n all finish on time step 2, then most of the workers will spend most of the time sitting doing nothing waiting for worker 1.

Comment: How can I ensure synchronous update of the parameters? If I perform the mean on a certain device, is the device context enough to make sure that the function waits for all dependent variables to be provided, or is there a chance old parameters are used?

Comment: If the dependency is fed in the Run call, then this value is guaranteed to be used in the computation. If the dependency is a variable which is not fed in the Run call, it'll just take whichever value was in that variable when the computation happens, which could be non-deterministic. You could add control dependencies to make sure your variable access waits for some other computation to complete first.

Comment: So what's the benefit of the asynchronous mean ？

Comment: In the case of asynchronous training, if the output of some workers would be overwritten, why we bother to run these workers?

Comment: @Fake we run all the workers because we don't know ahead of time which updates will be overwritten.