# Outputs of the distributed version of MNIST model

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am playing with the distributed version of the MNIST on CloudML and I am not sure to understand the logs displayed during the training phase:

```
INFO:root:Train [master/0], step 1693: Loss: 1.176, Accuracy: 0.464 (760.724 sec) 4.2 global steps/s, 4.2 local steps/s
INFO:root:Train [master/0], step 1696: Loss: 1.175, Accuracy: 0.464 (761.420 sec) 4.3 global steps/s, 4.3 local steps/s
INFO:root:Eval, step 1696: Loss: 0.990, Accuracy: 0.537
INFO:root:Train [master/0], step 1701: Loss: 1.175, Accuracy: 0.465 (766.337 sec) 1.0 global steps/s, 1.0 local steps/s
```

I am batching over 200 examples at a time, randomly.

Why is there such a gap between Train acc/loss and Eval acc/loss, the metrics for the eval set being significantly higher than for the train set, when it is usually the opposite?

Also, what is the difference between the global step and the local step?

The code I am talking about is [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/mnist/distributed/trainer). task.py is calling model.py, the file where the graph is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RE: gap between Train acc/loss and Eval acc/loss**

This is result of using exponential moving average to smooth out loss and accuracy between batches (otherwise plot is very noisy). The way the metrics are calculated on eval set and train set is different:

- the eval set loss and accuracy is calculated using a moving exponential average of all batches of examples in the eval set - after each run of the evaluation the moving average is reset, so each point represents single run - also all eval steps are calculated using a consistent checkpoint (consistent value of weights).
- the train set loss and accuracy is calculated using a moving exponential average of all batches of examples in training set during training process - the moving average is never reset so it can carry over past information for long time - and it is not based on a consistent checkpoint. This is a cheap to calculate approximation of the metrics.

We will be providing updated samples calculating loss on training and eval  set in consistent way. Surprisingly even with the update initially eval set gets higher accuracy than training set - probably all the data wasn't properly shuffled and randomly split into training and eval set - and eval set contains slightly 'easier' subset of the data. After more training steps the classifier starts to over-fit training data and accuracy on training set exceeds accuracy on eval set.

**RE: what is the difference between the global step and the local step?**
Local steps is number of batches processed by single worker (each worker logs this information), global steps is number of batches processed by all workers. When single worker is used the two numbers are equal. When using more workers in distributed setting the global step > local step.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing distributed training you can have more than 1 worker. Each of these workers can compute an update to the parameters. So each time a worker computes an update that counts as 1 local step. Depending on the type of training, [synchronous vs. asynchronous training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349316/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-computation-in-tensorflow), the updates can be combined in different ways before actually applying the update to the parameters.

For example, every worker might update the parameters, or you might average the updates from each worker and only apply update the parameters once.

The global step tells you how many times you actually updated the parameters. So if you have N workers and you apply each worker's update then N local steps should correspond to N global steps. On the other hand, if you have N workers and you take 1 update from each worker, average them, and then update the parameters, then you'd have 1 global step for every N local steps.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. But what about de discrepancy between training and eval metrics?

Comment: I tried swapping the train and eval datasets (so I was training on eval and evaluating on train) and it exhibits the same behavior. This may indicate a bug in the accuracy computation/reporting. We will investigate.

Comment: @rhaertel80, thank you for checking. I don't know what to think, I tried hypertune on a dataset of mine and got an accuracy of 100% and high loss on the eval set after 300 steps (for several combinations of parameters) while the accuracy on training was around 60%. It is almost with the same code..

Comment: @rhaertel80 Regarding Hypertune, note that [in the doc](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/training) you also achieve 100% accuracy on the MNIST data set for several combinations of hyperparameters. There might be some problem on your side. Opening an issue on the repo.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. See answer below for information about the samples.

Answer (score 1):

The training measures that are being reported are computed on just the "mini-batch" of examples used in that step (200 in your case).  The eval measures are reported on the entire evaluation set.

So, the mini-batch training statistics will be quite noisy.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigating the code in the example, the problem is that the accuracy reported over the training data is a moving average. Thus, the average reported at the current step is actually influenced by the average from many steps ago, which is typically lower. We will update the samples by not averaging with previous steps.